# How to navigate page in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, windows-phone-8.1

When I trying to navigate pages in Visual Studio 2015 but It shows an error when compiling.

Comment: Please read: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , specifically post your code here, do not include screenshots.

Comment: `public object NavigationService` remove that line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The accepted answer is not fully corrected, since `typeof` only accepts a `Type` not an `instance`.

As you can read in the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh771188.aspx) from MSDN, to navigate use:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
```